# How do I pull a value from a Paragraph field and put it in a template?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I would like to pull a value from a field I have in Paragraphs.

I have a content type called "Landing Pages" (landing_pages)

I have a paragraph type called "Landing Page" (landing_page)

The field in the said paragraph type that I would like to pull is called "Background Color" (field_background_color)

As you can probably guess, I would like the user to be able to set the background color of the individual Paragraph. I have figured out how to get the template to display said inline style, but I am puzzeled on how to get the value in the "style=background-color:" tag.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Here is the template file snippet that I'm working with:
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
{% block paragraph %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }} style="background-color:{{ paragraph.landing_page.field_background_color.value }}">
    {% block content %}
      {{ content }}
     
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}

Comment: In the respective paragraph template, its simply: `paragraph.field_background_color.value`

Comment: ahhh....thank you!